# Get BuildContext when not available through parameter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there an alternative to `Navigator.push` which doesn't require a context? Here is my problem.

I have a very nested and deep callstack and not each function has a BuildContext parameter. Is there any other way to get the current BuildContext than through passing it from one function to another?

**test1.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext) {
...
new GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => foo1() // very deep callstack until it calls foo30
...
}
```

**test2.dart**

```
void foo30() {
    // need context here like:
    BuildContext context = IHopeThatExists.getCurrentContext();

    // why do I need that? Navigator.push needs a context or is there an alternative? FYI: I don't need to go back to the previous page though
    Navigator.push(context, ..)
}
```

Comment: you can create a field of Buildcontext and assign context to it in build method of StatefulWidget State. This way the context will be available everywhere in State class

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Builder` widget:

```
return Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(...);
      },
      ...
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your call stack is that deep you might want to consider refactoring =D. But that aside, if you use a StatefulWidget it has a [`context`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/context.html) property which is the same as what is passed to the build function.

And FYI - from the [`State.build` docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/build.html):

> The BuildContext argument is always the same as the context property
>   of this State object and will remain the same for the lifetime of this
>   object. The BuildContext argument is provided redundantly here so that
>   this method matches the signature for a WidgetBuilder.